# Detecting sample data that is related to only a certain part of a sound file

Tags: java, audio, fft, wav

I want to extract sample byte data that is related to a certain area of a sound clip like, a word in a sound clip, so that I get a collection of sample data that is related only to the particular word which then I can send through a FFT. How will I be able to identify this collection of data from a collection of bytes that are there for the whole sound file? Some of the byte data from the file looks like this after converting them to 2 byte values because its a 16 bit sound file (44100Hz 15 sec).

```
49150.0
43010.0
15622.0
58886.0
19460.0
35583.0
0.0
7930.0
507.0
2303.0
59897.0
39419.0
517.0
6663.0
9989.0
13055.0
9210.0
```

I am aware that this data is in the time domain and I am not seeing any significant changes in data like a collection of 0’s to identify silence. Will I be able to do this in the time domain or would I be having to take this data to the frequency domain and then filter the unnecessary data and do a reverse FFT to get a collection of data that make sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, perhaps the easiest, is to load the sound file into an audio editing application that lets you set the start and end points of a selection, and just listen and move the selection points until you hear what you want.  Trying to find an accurate and robust description of those end points that is usable by a software algorithm is a much more difficult problem.

Comment: thanks. but this is for a Academic assignment. Is it not even possible to identify a segment of where there is most likely to have sound. will i be able to extract only that few sample values.